# Embedded non-relational (nosql) data store

Tags: .net, sqlite, nosql, embedded-database

I'm thinking about using/implementing some kind of an embedded key-value (or document) store for my Windows desktop application. I want to be able to store various types of data (GPS tracks would be one example) and of course be able to query this data. The amount of data would be such that it couldn't all be loaded into memory at the same time.

I'm thinking about using sqlite as a storage engine for a key-value store, something like [y-serial](http://yserial.sourceforge.net/), but written in .NET. I've also read about [FriendFeed's usage of MySQL to store schema-less data](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql), which is a good pointer on how to use RDBMS for non-relational data. sqlite seems to be a good option because of its simplicity, portability and library size.

My question is whether there are any other options for an embedded non-relational store? It doesn't need to be distributable and it doesn't have to support transactions, but it does have to be accessible from .NET and it should have a small download size.

UPDATE: I've found an article titled [SQLite as a Key-Value Database](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=KeyValueDatabase)  which compares sqlite with Berkeley DB, which is an embedded key-value store library.

Answer (score 19):

Windows has a built-in embedded non-relational store. It is called ESENT and is used by several Windows applications, including the Active Directory and Windows Desktop Search.

http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2008/10/23/esent-extensible-storage-engine-api-in-the-windows-sdk.aspx

If you want .NET access you can use the ManagedEsent layer on CodePlex.

http://managedesent.codeplex.com/

That project has a PersistentDictionary class that implements a key-value store that implements the IDictionary interface, but is backed by a database.

Comment: @Laurion, I've seen ESENT and was initially very excited. The only problem is that it's Windows-only (think Mono + Linux/Mac).

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/home).  It looks as though it can be embedded and is schemaless and works with .NET

From the website:

- Scalable infrastructure: Raven builds on top of existing, proven and scalable infrastructure
- Simple Windows configuration: Raven is simple to setup and run on windows as either a service or IIS7 website
- Transactional: Raven support System.Transaction with ACID transactions. If you put data in it, that data is going to stay there
- Map/Reduce: Easily define map/reduce indexes with Linq queries
- .NET Client API: Raven comes with a fully functional .NET client API which implements Unit of Work and much more
- RESTful: Raven is built around a RESTful API

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would go for SQLite with NHibernate (and Fluent NHibernate). NHibernate can generate the database schema automatically for your classes, so you just need to specify what classes you want to persist, and that's quite easy with Fluent NHibernate. Furthermore, you can search for specific objects and you don't need to load all data to memory.

Comment: But he wanted a schema-less store....

Comment: Astor is right: I want to avoid the relational model. I want to be able to store practically any kind of data without first having to prepare the database schema for it. Also, having a strict relational model can be problematic if the data structure changes later - I would need to write SQL change scripts for the existing data in the store.

Comment: I know what he is looking for but such tools like NHibernate with schema generation hide the relational aspect nearly completely. You do not need to define any schema but only the mapping for you classes (which is really straight forward with Fluent NHibernate) and when your classes change, you will need to do some kind of update in any persistence strategy.

Comment: I appreciate that, but hiding relational aspects isn't the same as not having relational model at all. And in practice this hiding goes only so far - sooner or later you need to deal with it "manually" (like in the case of the changes in the model). On the other hand, if you store the data as documents (which some NoSQL solutions do), you don't really need to update the old data - you just need to make sure you support the reading of the data in the older form.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the KISS principle to your problem I would recommend you use files.

As in filename is the key.
File contents is the value.
Windows folder is the index.

Simple, quick, efficient, flexible, and foolproof (providing the fools have low intelligence).

Comment: Nice approach, although I feel using files for storing values would be a bit over-the-top for simple values (a single integer, for example).

Comment: The question sort of implies that what is being stored can be quiet large (documents / too much data to be loaded into memory). One of the advantages of the file approach is that you get a nice set of Stream handling classes for free, which is very useful when dealing with big chunks of data and much cleaner than for example splitting data into arbitary nMB blobs and storing it in a database.

Comment: True. What about physical limits of the file system? How would such store behave when the number of records reaches > 100.000?

Also: when I talked about "too much data", I meant the _whole_ database - I mentioned this to avoid answers like object tree serialization and similar.

Answer (score 2):

Could you create a simple sqlite database with two columns:

```
==documents==
id|data
```

and data would be json data.

You could also create a key table which would be:

```
==keys==
keyname|keyvalue|id
```

that would be indexed on keyname and keyvalue for quick lookups.

A single db file could be a collection, and you could create multiple db files for multiple collections.

You could use folders as "dbs" to match mongodb's hierarchy of db->collection->document

Comment: Just a note: you would create a template sqlite db file, and copy that for any time you needed to create a new collection. 

If anyone wants to create a php setup to handle this and open source it, let me know. I think it would be great, but never bothered to make it myself.

Comment: your suggestions are in the direction of how y-serial does things. Have you seen it? http://yserial.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Nope, but I am looking for a php solution myself.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd add an answer in case anyone stumbles on it. My company just released an open source embedded XML database for the .NET platform called Nxdb. It's under the Apache 2.0 license and has been in development and use internally for several years. It's basically a binding to a cross-compiled (using IKVM) version of BaseX (a fantastic Java XML database) along with extra functionality for the embedded use case and the .NET environment. The project page is here: https://dracorp.assembla.com/spaces/nxdb

XML works well for this type of data store given that as long as the content you're trying to store is serializable to text you can store complex hierarchical trees. In fact, if you access the database directly, you don't ever even have to touch "XML". It can also be queried with XQuery, a powerful and complete query language.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your kind mention of y_serial... more precisely, it is a Python module:

warehouse Python objects with SQLite

"Serialization + persistance :: in a few lines of code, compress and annotate Python objects into SQLite; then later retrieve them chronologically by keywords without any SQL. Most useful "standard" module for a database to store schema-less data."

http://yserial.sourceforge.net

In my experience, SQLite is a faster and more reliable choice than most databases (including PostgresQL and Berkeley DB) for the majority of projects -- and of course, it does not need a server daemon.

yserial is very easy to implement (and far faster than the "filename is the key / file contents is the value" approach ;-)

Comment: Yes, I really like y-serial's approach, especially since it uses sqlite. Keep up the good work! Maybe when I get some time from my other projects, I'll try to do something similar in C# :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one https://github.com/mdsoftware/mData. Small, free and quite unusual. Lisp-like data query language, expression compiler, high-performance binary serialization, all included.